# Easiest way to definitely, positively delete a file in macOS (10.14+) as root?

Tags: terminal, mojave, root

I have a 1TB main drive where ~400GB seemingly got stuck in `/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/` after the 10.14 update.

I managed to delete most of it, but some files and folders are extremely resilient to being deleted.

For example I am stuck with a folder:

```
/Volumes/Time Machine[...]/private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles`
```

I am unable to delete it, even trying `rm -rf` as root. When I examine the folder from the terminal I get:

```
sh-3.2# whoami
root

sh-3.2# pwd
/Volumes/Time Machine[...]/private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles

sh-3.2# ls -la
ls: Store: Operation not permitted
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root  wheel  96 Oct 12 22:18 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root  wheel  96 Oct 12 22:18 ..
```

Interestingly enough, when I open the same folder in `mc`, a file `?Store` is present:

[image]

Since I have a bunch of folders around with similar problems, I was wondering what the easiest and most convenient way to delete all of them is.

Things I tried that don't work:

- `sudo rm -rf ...`
- `mc` -> `F8`
- Granting Terminal full disk access in security settings

Is there a tool or simple command that acts like `rm -f` and really just deletes a file, no matter what?

Comment: Let me guess: You also can't access `Store` through `ll /private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles` (on your main disk, not the backup)?

Comment: If I run `ls -la /private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles` I get `ls: Store: Operation not permitted`.

Comment: What happens if you disable SIP? Not being able to do things as root is an indication that SIP is blocking you.

Comment: @Gilby This was my first thought too, but SIP shouldn’t be preventing the deletion of files on an external volume! It only applies to the boot volume.

Comment: Have you tried running first aid on the disk? I wonder if there's some file system corruption at play here...

Comment: Have you tried deleting with tmutil?